# Logging in Razor view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, view, razor

How to add logging in razor views? I would like to add debug statements using logging tool such as log4net?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with the other replies but this would be for temparary debugging such finding out count or similar scenario.

After fiddling around a little, following syntax worked.

```
@{ ViewBag.Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Products.cshtml");}
```

`@ViewBag.Log.Debug("Products count = " + Model.Products.ToList().Count);`

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly discourage you from doing that.

It sounds to me that you have logic in your views. It makes the views hard to maintain and even harder to test the logic.

Move the logic either to your controllers or your view models. And log in those instead.

Comment: This should be a comment. It's sometimes hard to draw that line between telling them how to do it "right" and to just help them with their issue. While I agree with your sentiment, there may be legit reasons to try and debug in a view. Either way, answers like this aren't really helpful.

Comment: Moving the logic to the controller or the view model will indeed help with the issue. And the amount of effort required to do so is minimal. If my answer would have said something that was tedious or time consuming I would have agreed with you.

Comment: How do you know that the logic can be moved, let alone with minimal effort?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be better off with an application wide logging approach as you don't want to catching logic errors in your view. Logic should be in controllers and (to an extent) models.

Have a look here -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363794/what-does-an-mvc-basecontroller-with-logging-look-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363794/what-does-an-mvc-basecontroller-with-logging-look-like/6187713#6187713) to see how to log errors and catch exceptions throughout your site.